# Sub-query to get highest value

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I get the max value per supplier, so I want the data to only have 1 supplier with the highest value

[this my result right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuoDp.png)

```
SELECT sup_nama, ([Training].[dbo].[Pengadaan_Detail]. pengd_jumlah * [Training].[dbo].[Pengadaan_Detail].pengd_harga) AS 
    Total_Pengadaan
    FROM [Training].[dbo].[Pengadaan_Header] 
    LEFT JOIN  [Training].[dbo].[Supplier]
    ON  [Training].[dbo].[Pengadaan_Header].supplier_id = [Training].[dbo].[Supplier].sup_id
    LEFT JOIN [Training].[dbo].[Pengadaan_Detail] 
    ON  [Training].[dbo].[Pengadaan_Header].peng_id = [Training].[dbo].[Pengadaan_Detail].peng_id
    LEFT JOIN [Training].[dbo].[Item_Master]    
    ON [Training].[dbo].[Item_Master].item_id = [Training].[dbo].[Pengadaan_Detail].item_id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT ([Training].[dbo].[Pengadaan_Detail]. pengd_jumlah * [Training].[dbo].[Pengadaan_Detail].pengd_harga) AS 
        Total_Pengadaans FROM [Training].[dbo].[Pengadaan_Detail] 
        GROUP BY ([Training].[dbo].[Pengadaan_Detail]. pengd_jumlah * [Training].[dbo].[Pengadaan_Detail].pengd_harga)
        ) s ON [Training].[dbo].[Pengadaan_Detail].peng_id = [Training].[dbo].[Pengadaan_Header].peng_id

    GROUP BY sup_nama, ([Training].[dbo].[Pengadaan_Detail]. pengd_jumlah * [Training].[dbo].[Pengadaan_Detail].pengd_harga)
```

I will sort by sup_name when the value is largest

Please help me.

Comment: Check out `row_number()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to deal with needing only one row that meets a condition (such as the "max") is to use `row_number() over(...)` within a subquery, and then only select the generated row number when it equals 1 e.g:

```
SELECT
      pheader.peng_id
    , pdetail.Total_Pengadaan
FROM [Training].[dbo].[Pengadaan_Header] AS pheader
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
          pd.peng_id
        , (pd.pengd_jumlah * pd.pengd_harga) AS Total_Pengadaans
        , row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY pd.peng_id 
            ORDER BY (pd.pengd_jumlah * pd.pengd_harga) DESC
            ) AS rn
    FROM [Training].[dbo].[Pengadaan_Detail] AS pd
    ) AS pdetail
    ON pheader.peng_id = pdetail.peng_id
        AND pdetail.rn = 1
```

Row numbering commences at 1 for each `peng_id` and the highest value of `(pd.pengd_jumlah * pd.pengd_harga)`, for all other values calculated the row numbers will be greater then 1. Then when we join the subquery to the main table we only allow 1 row for each `peng_id` as part of the join conditions.

---

`row_number()` simply starts at 1 for each "partition" and increments by one for each row according to the given order. The `over clause` supplies the `partition by` (*think of this as being the columns you would otherwise group by*) and the `order by` is also specified in the over clause. So the first row in the specified order at the beginning of each partition will always have a row_number() of 1.

The advantage over using `group by` and aggregation is that you will always get a single row which is harder to achieve via aggregations. Imaging a query where you calculate the SUM, then the MAX of that sum, this requires 2 sets of calculations.

Comment: its works but i dont know about row_number() and OVER work, thanks

Comment: can the code use an aggregate subquery?

Comment: see extra note in answer